# TypeTag for a type containing an abstract type

Tags: scala, abstract-type

We have a trait `Foo` and are thinking about a method `cast` that takes a type parameter `A <: Foo` and a parameter `f: Foo` and returns `Some(f: A)` if `f <: A`, else `None`:

```
trait Foo
def cast[A <: Foo](f: Foo): Option[A] = ???
```

If `Foo` extendings will never be generic, then attaching a `ClassTag` is the conclusion:

```
def cast[A <: Foo : ClassTag](f: Foo) = f match {
  case f: A => Some(f)
  case _ => None
}
...
class Bar extends Foo
class Hoo extends Foo
println cast[Bar](new Bar) //→ Some(Bar)
println cast[Hoo](new Bar) //→ None
```

But what if there exists some `Foo` with an abstract type? Such like:

```
trait FooTyped extends Foo {
  type T
}
```

Then the `cast` just gets destroyed at all:

```
type FooT[A] = FooTyped{ type T = A }
...
val fint: FooT[Int] = new FooTyped{ type T = Int }
println cast[FooT[String]](fint) //→ Some(FooTyped) OH WHAT?
```

This happens because `ClassTag` doesn't care of type parameters and abstract types.

So we're going to use `TypeTag` that does keep track of them... But I don't know exactly how.

Please help me finish writing this article :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ghik answer is correct. As a supplement I provide one possible way to achieve this:

With this helper class:

```
class Caster[B : TypeTag](f: B) {
  def cast[A <: Foo : TypeTag] = 
    if(typeOf[B] <:< typeOf[A]) Some(f) else None
}
```

You would get the expected answers like this:

```
println(new Caster(new Bar).cast[Bar]) //→ Some(Bar)
println(new Caster(new Bar).cast[Hoo]) //→ None
println(new Caster(fint).cast[FooT[String]]) //→ None
```

Answer (score 2):

Having:

```
trait Foo
def cast[A <: Foo](f: Foo): Option[A] = ???
```

You're going to need not only the `TypeTag` for target type `A` but also `TypeTag` for value `f`. Objects in JVM don't carry full type information in runtime.